# Weibliche Form zu (Lego-)Männchen

Tags: noun, gender

Kleine Spielzeugfiguren werden ja mitunter als **Männchen** bezeichnet.
In der Zoologie ist der weibliche Gegenpart zu diesem Begriff das **Weibchen**.

Aber ich finde, **Lego-Weibchen** hört sich irgendwie seltsam an. Manchmal den Begriff findet man ja auch **Lego-Frauchen**, aber das wäre ja der Gegenpart zum (meines Wissens nie verwendeten) **Lego-Herrchen**.

Was ist die korrekte weiblichen Form?

Comment: Siehe bspw. auch _Ampelmännchen_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Lego-Männchen" scheint deutlich weniger gebräuchlich zu sein als "Lego-Figur" (Google-Treffer: 6.270.000 zu 514.000). "Figur" trägt m.E. keine spezifische Bedeutung, was das Geschlecht des dargestellten Wesens betrifft - also einfach "Lego-Figur" verwenden, und alles ist gut.

Comment: Irgendwie hatte ich **Lego-Männchen** als gegeben angenommen (wahrscheinlich war der Begriff in meiner eigenen Kindheit verwendet worden). Aber auch die offizielle Webseite spricht tatsächlich überall von **Minifiguren**

Comment: Die Dinger heißen deshalb offiziell Minifiguren, weil es von Lego in den 1970ern eine Nummer größere Figuren mit Arm- und Beingelenken gab. https://steinwurf.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/figuren-universalkasten-205-1/

Comment: Ich habe hier den Verdacht einer starken Diskrepanz zwischen Texten und gesprochener Sprache.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper   In der Tat. Weder Treffer bei Google noch die Wortwahl im Legokatalog sagen uns, welches Wort im Kinderzimmer und im Familienkreis im Alltag wirklich verwendet wird. Ich würde allerdings wetten, es ist eher "Lego-Männchen" als "Lego-Figur" oder gar "Minifigur". Ein Elternteil würde - denke ich - eher rufen: "Lisa, jetzt räum' mal deine Legomännchen vom Tisch, wir wollen essen" als "Lisa, jetzt räum' mal deine Legofiguren vom Tisch."